# How to derive a column based on two different merged dimensions in SAP Business Objects?

Tags: merge, business-objects

I have two tables, and I want to derive one column from Table1 to Table2 by common fields Name and Color (by merging).
But until I was using only one merged dimension and it was working well for me.
Now, for two dimensions, it is not working.

If I have two tables :

**Table1 Name : Fruits**

```
|--------|--------|---------------|
| Name   | Color  | Rateperunit   |
|--------|--------|---------------|
| banana | yellow | 3             |
|--------|--------|---------------|
| apple  | red    | 25            |
|--------|--------|---------------|
| apple  | green  | 30            |
|--------|--------|---------------|
```

**Table2 Name : Purchase**

```
|--------|---------|-------------|-----------|----------|
| Item   | Color   | Rateperunit | Noofitems | Totalbill| 
|--------|---------|-------------|-----------|----------|
| apple  | green   |30           | 3         | 90       |
|--------|---------|-------------|-----------|----------|
```

Comment: If you had a unique ID on your Fruit table that was subsequently saved in your Purchase table you would have no problem merging. Having said that I am going to see what I can figure out with two columns. What version of BusinessObjects are you using? In an upcoming version (4.2 or 4.3) you will be able to merge variables. So then you would be able create variables and concatenate the fruit names and colors from each table and then merge them.

Comment: Also, what is your data source and underlying database (e.g. SQL Server, Oracle, etc.)?

Comment: Can you specifically state what your expected result is and what is not working?